# Retrieving Data From Object Not Working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, ios, sql, cordova, ionic-framework

I've attached `$cordovaSQLite` to my ionic app. Here is a basic example of the code.

```
function retrieve() {
var q = $q.defer();

var query = 'SELECT user_credentials, user_id FROM Users;';

$ionicPlatform.ready(function (){
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
      console.log("found user");
      console.log(res);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      q.resolve(res.rows[0]);
    } else {
      console.log("no rows found");
      q.resolve(false);

    }
  }, function (err) {
    q.reject(err);
  });
});

return q.promise;
}
```

Here is the code to open up the db.

```
if(window.cordova) {
  // App syntax
  db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB( "CoolApp.db" );
} else {
  // Ionic serve syntax
  db = window.openDatabase("CoolApp.db", "1.0", "Cool App", -1);
}
```

When I test my app on Chrome, my logs show this

```
rows: SQLResultSetRowList
  0: Object
    user_credentials: "asdf"
    user_id: 234
  length: 1
rowsAffected: 0
```

However when I view the logs when running on my iOS app or Safari, I receive

```
{"rows":{"length":1},"rowsAffected":0,"insertId":1}
```

My question is why am I not receiving the value of `rows`? Why does this work on the browser but not on iOS?

Comment: but in browser also rowsaffected is 0 !

Comment: The rowsAffected are irrelevant to me. What matters is the content of the row. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @jason328 Are there any records in the phone's database?

Comment: Yes the database is populated.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the results by querying the rows.item method with the corresponding index if multiple results were returned.

```
var elements = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
    elements.push(result.rows.item(i));
}
return elements;
```

Where result is the object returned by $cordovaSQL when its promise is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to instantiate a webSQL instead of SQLite DB for your browser?

You can always just go back to SQLite for your device, but modern browsers like Chrome and Firefox don't support SQLite.

Comment: Yes I did. When I open db I have to set to open it depending on if I'm using a browser or mobile device.